# NoMethod Error - One to Many Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

Trying to debug something for hours which is not making any sense

The error is:

```
undefined method `proposals' for nil:NilClass
```

I have two one-to-many associations in the following models:

```
entrepreneur.rb
...
 has_many :findentrepreneurs, :dependent => :destroy
...
```

finentrepreneur.rb

```
 belongs_to :entrepreneur
    has_many :proposals
```

proposal.rb

```
belongs_to :findentrepreneur
```

I did a nested routing model using the following:

```
resources :entrepreneurs do
             resources :messages do
               collection do
                 post :delete_selected
               end
             end
             resources :findentrepreneurs do
            resources :proposals
          end
           end
```

and finally my proposals_controller.rb new action

```
def new
    @proposal = @findentrepreneurs.proposals.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @proposal }
    end
  end
```

Hope someone can help

Thankyou

Comment: Where do you set @findentrepreneurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowhere do you actually initialize `@findentrepreneurs`. Rails isn't magic, you need to actually assign something to that variable before you use it. Otherwise, its value is `nil`, and you get the error you're seeing, which is telling you that you've invoked the method `proposals` on `nil`.

Comment: yeah, guess your right. Sorry about the stupid question. I'm a newbie with rails...